# Bad vertical allignment with fontawesome

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I am rendering the following component:

```
<a id="ember527" class="ember-view" href="#/billing"><i class="icon-euro icon-2x"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Billing</a>
```

An it shows like this:

[image]

The icon is alligned with the text, but I would like it to be centered vertically. Is this possible?

EDIT: take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gonvaled/QHJ4f/)

Comment: Added. Not exactly my markup, but close enough, and the problem is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this to your css file :

```
.icon-euro {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by setting to the icon the `display: block;` property and `float: left;.

If for other needs you need to adjust also the "Billing" vertical alignment, you can insert it into a span and give to it the same "display: block;" property.

Then, play with top margins and then you're ok ;)

Hope it helps, good luck!